# Prolog: If a float is input, output prints out error

Tags: prolog

I'm new to SWI-prolog and I'm having trouble with my code. I want it to determine if the input is a multiple of 5 and not an even number but if it's not an integer it should print out an error message. So far I have this but it's not printing out the error message and instead it's just telling me it's a type error.

```
MultOf5(N) :- 
0 is N mod 5, \+ 0 is N mod 2. 
MultOf5(Other) :-
N is Other,
print("ERROR: The given parameter is not an integer").
```

It's printing out this when I input:

```
?-Multof5(4.7)
 Singleton variables: [N]
 mod/2: Type error: `integer' expected, found `4.2' (a float)
```

Please let me know where I'm going wrong and what I could do to fix this. It's saying I have a singleton variable too. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noted issues in the posted code:

- In Prolog, a predicate cannot start with a capital letter. So
  `MultOf5(N) ...` is invalid. Judging from the messages you are
  showing, I assume that's not how your code is really written.
- `multOf5(Other) ...` only refers to `N` one time, and it's not otherwise
  used. That's what generates a singleton warning.
- `mod`, as you know, operates on integers, and your first clause attempts `mod` on the value `4.2`, which will fail. You can use `integer(N)` which succeeds if `N` is integer.

I would prefer the positive `1 is N mod 2` over the negative `\+ 0 is N mod 2`.

```
oddMultOf5(N) :-
    (   integer(N)
    ->  0 is N mod 5,
        1 is N mod 2
    ;   print("ERROR: The given parameter is not an integer")
    ).
```

Comment: yeah sorry I changed up the code a bit from what I wrote so I can just get the point across. Thanks! that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Is there a way for me to cut off the code after it prints off the error? I added the ! before the ;(or) but it tells me its an error.

Comment: @tadashi You would want the cut with the `print`. You could write it as `print( ...), !`. Since `print` doesn't have any choice points, you could also put it before: `!, print(...)`.